# What does "rose 2.27% on the month" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence:

> Industrial production rose 2.27 percent on the month in April after surging 33.04 percent in March, with year-on-year growth picking up from a decline of 1.1 percent to an increase of 3.9 percent.

What does "on the month" mean here? Does it mean "month to date"?

Comment: I suspect what should have been written is *rose 2.27 percent **in** the month **of** April*. Writing *2.27 percent in April* is fine, but the author most likely got confused when trying to insert *the month* for some reason, and ended up using the wrong prepositions.

Comment: @Jason: No, this is an idiom that has bled over from (American) sports. Statements like "That makes 23 home runs **on** the year for Bates" are quite commonly heard here.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this, from the UK Telegraph, May 15, 2020:

> Sales dived by more than 16pc on the month in April, the steepest fall since monthly records began more than half a century ago, and came on top of the 8pc drop in March.

https://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2020/05/15/us-retail-sales-plunge-april/

The terminology “on the month” is used to refer to a percentage change from the previous month, in contrast to an annual rate or the percentage change from the same month in the previous year.